# Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to write a script that will vol up radio in the background

```
#!/bin/sh

for (( i = 80 ; i <= 101; i++ )) 
 do 
  amixer cset numid=1 i$% sleep 60;
done
```

But i have problem:

```
alarmclock-vol.sh: 3: alarmclock-vol.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Comment: Because [sh isn't bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash). `for (( … ))` is not available in sh.

Comment: @kojiro: `sh` may or may not be `bash`; on some systems, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, and the above script may work. In any case, you certainly shouldn't assume that it is.

Comment: @KeithThompson, though even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, bash behaves differently when invoked as sh (posix mode enabled). Therefore, even when sh is bash, "sh is not bash" still applies.

Comment: @geirha: On my Debian 6 system, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, and the `for (( ... ))` syntax works in a script with `#!/bin/sh`; with `#!/bin/dash` it gives me `"Syntax error: Bad for loop variable"`. (It's bash 4.1.5 if that matters.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, some syntax still works (like `for ((...))` in this case),  some acts a little differently (the `source` and `.` builtins), while some syntax is disabled outright (like process substitution `<(...)` and `>(...)` ). Those are just examples that came to mind right now.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `for (( expr ; expr ; expr ))` syntax is not available in `sh`. Switch to bash or ksh93 if you want to use that syntax. Otherwise, the equivalent for sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=80
while [ "$i" -le 101 ]; do
    amixer cset numid=1 "$i%"
    sleep 60
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: FYI, to change to bash, change your hashbang (the first line of your script) to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 4):

use bash instead of sh

```
bash alarmclock-vol
```

Answer (score 3):

**try using**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

**instead of**

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can achieve this is by giving the file **execution permission**. Below are the commands:

Instead of `sh filename.sh`

Do this:

```
chmod +x filename.sh
./filename.sh
```

You can see in this [image: picture]

for the same code that didn't run with **sh** but runs after giving **execution permission**.

The shell script that I used here is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++)); 
do
  echo $i
done
```