# Difference between source, zsh, "." and directly shell script calling

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, dot-source

I have very simple script(for_loop4.sh) as shown below.

```
# !/bin/zsh
#

for (( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ))
do
    echo $i;
done
```

I'm using zsh 5.0.7 for my shell.

When running this script using source, zsh and . command, 
it works as expected. But, when calling this script directly, 
it fails with the message "Bad for loop variable".

Why this happens ? 
What's difference ?

```
$ source ./for_loop4.sh
0
1
2

$ zsh ./for_loop4.sh
0
1
2

$ . ./for_loop4.sh
0
1
2

$ ./for_loop4.sh
./for_loop4.sh: 4: ./for_loop4.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Comment: Is the execute bit set on for_loop4.sh ? Does the system have the same results if you chmod +x ./for_loop.sh ?

Comment: I get different results on my Mac, which is running zsh 5.0.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error: Bad for loop variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358065/syntax-error-bad-for-loop-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is wrong:

```
# !/bin/zsh
```

It should be:

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Thanks !! This fixes my problem.

Comment: Just for completeness: What happens with the wrong line is that the default shell - `/bin/sh` - is used. In this case `/bin/sh` does not seem to be a link to/a copy of `zsh` or `bash` (I am guessing `dash`) and does not support this type of `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that where is your zsh installed. It can be installed into /usr/ directory.
You can type,

> $ which zsh